# PHP. Как получить id из тега list html

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

```
Только начинаю изучать php и пытаюсь понять, как получить id выбранного элемента из list. С помощью полученного id хочу выгружать ту или иную базу данных


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<header>
    <h1>REAL ESTATE</h1>
    <a class="btnreg" href=" register.php"> Зарегистрироваться </a>
    <a class="btnvhod" href=" login.php"> Войти </a>
</header>

<body>


    <main>
        <?php

        require_once 'connection.php';
        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db)
            or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_errno($link));
        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            echo 123;
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <p><input list="tablechoice" type="text" name="table_c" placeholder="Выберите таблицу" /></p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="tabch" value="Отправить">
            </p>
            <datalist id="tablechoice">
                <option value="Квартиры"></option>
                <option value="Риэлторы"></option>
                <option value="Сделки"></option>
            </datalist>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (!empty($_POST['tabch']))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Результат будет:

```
array(2) { ["table_c"]=> string(12) "Сделки" ["tabch"]=> string(18) "Отправить" }
```

Т.е. выбранный элемент: $_POST['table_c']

Comment: Спасибо огромное)